# ¿Qué significa este error? error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive] y error: expected ‘)’ before string constant

Tags: c++, operador

soy nueva en programar y no entiendo a que se refieren estos dos errores:

> ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
>
> error: expected ‘)’ before string constant

Estoy haciendo un código para diferenciar vocales cerradas y abiertas:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int
main ()
{
  char letra;
  cout << "Ingrese una letra:\n";
  cin >> letra;
  if (letra == "A" || letra == "E" ||letra == "O" || letra == "a" || letra == "e" || letra == "o")
    {
      cout << "La letra es una vocal abierta\n";
    }
    else
    {
    if (letra == "I" || letra == "i" || letra "U" || letra "u")
    {
     cout << "La letra es una vocal cerrada\n";}
     else 
     cout << "La letra es una consonante\n";
    }
    cout << "Recordar: Una vocal cerrada es aquella que no necesita una abertura máxima de la boca sino que se produce en un mínimo espacio entre la lengua y el paladar, colocándose la lengua en la parte superior de la boca.y una vocal abierta es se caracteriza por la posición de la lengua dentro de la cavidad bucal, colocándose en la parte inferior de la boca, de manera que la cavidad bucal se amplia para producir el sonido vocálico.";
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuándo declaras una variable estática como la palabra `"hola"` que estamos asignando a la variable `a` en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
string a = "hola"
```

Estás declarando una `string` que se representa por medio de un puntero, esto está defindio por el uso de las comillas `""`. Lo que pasa con tu código es que las vocales se están interpretando como strings... Si quieres declarar las variables como `char` para poder hacer la comparación debes de utilizar apostrofe sencilla, como por ejemplo: `'a'`, de lo contrario se interpretará como una `string`(puntero) y el compilador no sabrá como realizar la comparación entre un puntero y un número, tal y como dice el error que obtienes.

Al final tu código debería de verse así:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  char letra;
  cout << "Ingrese una letra:\n";
  cin >> letra;
  if (letra == 'A' || letra == 'E' ||letra == 'O' || letra == 'a' || letra == 'e' || letra == 'o')
    {
      cout << "La letra es una vocal abierta\n";
    }
    else
    {
    if (letra == 'I' || letra == 'i' || letra == 'U' || letra == 'u')
    {
     cout << "La letra es una vocal cerrada\n";}
     else 
     cout << "La letra es una consonante\n";
    }
    cout << "Recordar: Una vocal cerrada es aquella que no necesita una abertura máxima de la boca sino que se produce en un mínimo espacio entre la lengua y el paladar, colocándose la lengua en la parte superior de la boca.y una vocal abierta es se caracteriza por la posición de la lengua dentro de la cavidad bucal, colocándose en la parte inferior de la boca, de manera que la cavidad bucal se amplia para producir el sonido vocálico.";
    return 0;
}
```

### En resumen:

Si vas a definir un char hazlo como:

```
'a'
```

Si vas a definir una string:

```
"a"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Me sirvió un montón y ahora ya me queda claro.